# Cannot create a table in mysql error(150)

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to create 3 tables called curenttasks, originaltasks and previoustasks. I make one table and copied to other two. But one table cannot create while other 2 are created successfully.

The three table are:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `CurrentTasks`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `CurrentTasks` (
  `taskID` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `taskName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `isActive` boolean DEFAULT TRUE,   
  `startDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `endDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `completeDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `complexityID` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `managerID` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
  `projectID` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
  `requirementName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `xPos` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `yPos` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `stageName` enum('Definition','Design','Development','Testing','Evaluation') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Definition',
  PRIMARY KEY (`taskID`)

) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `CurrentTasks`
--

LOCK TABLES `PreviousTasks` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `PreviousTasks` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `PreviousTasks` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Table structure for table `PreviousTasks`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `PreviousTasks`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `PreviousTasks` (
  `taskID` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `taskName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `isActive` boolean DEFAULT TRUE,   
  `startDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `endDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `completeDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `complexityID` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `managerID` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
  `projectID` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
  `requirementName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `xPos` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `yPos` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `stageName` enum('Definition','Design','Development','Testing','Evaluation') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Definition',
  PRIMARY KEY (`taskID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uniquePreviousTasks` (`requirementName`,`projectID`,`taskName`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `PreviousTasks`
--

LOCK TABLES `PreviousTasks` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `PreviousTasks` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `PreviousTasks` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Table structure for table `OriginalTasks`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `OriginalTasks`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `OriginalTasks` (
  `taskID` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `taskName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `isActive` boolean DEFAULT TRUE,
  `startDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `endDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `completeDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `complexityID` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `managerID` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
  `projectID` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
  `requirementName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `xPos` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `yPos` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `stageName` enum('Definition','Design','Development','Testing','Evaluation') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Definition',
  PRIMARY KEY (`taskID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uniqueOriginalTasks` (`requirementName`,`projectID`,`taskName`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `OriginalTasks`
--

LOCK TABLES `OriginalTasks` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `OriginalTasks` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `OriginalTasks` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

The currenttasks cannot cteate, the error is:

> ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'rem.currenttasks' (errno: 150)

I just very confused because I delete currenttasks and copied previoustasks to it, replace every previous with current, but it still cannot work.

Comment: 1005 (ER_CANT_CREATE_TABLE)

Cannot create table. If the error message refers to error 150, table creation failed because a foreign key constraint was not correctly formed.

Comment: but in this table, there is no foreign key at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to delete lines between 28-31. PreviousTasks table is not created yet, but those lines tries to alter table. Also same thing exist at lines 64-67.